# How to get a java date format to an XML?

Tags: java, xml

I want to generate an XML file for the data inside the Java file. There is an date filed and I want to retrieve it as a Date to the XML file.  I have used createTextNode but it expects a string.

Here is my code

```
Element doctor=doc.createElement("doctor");
        doctor.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(prescriptionData.getDoctor().getName()));
        prescription.appendChild(doctor);
        Element patient=doc.createElement("patient");
        patient.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(prescriptionData.getPatient().getPatientName()));
        prescription.appendChild(patient);
        Element date=doc.createElement("date");
        date.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(prescriptionData.getPrescribedDate()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do `prescriptionData.getPrescribedDate().toString()`

Answer (score 0):

Try to look for JAXBContext and Marshaller to create an XML file.